# python suds UsernameToken

Tags: python, soap, suds

Code:

```
security = Security()
token = UsernameToken('b77a5c561934e089', 'kmfHkNZyn1U/pGAiY3+h0BoHdKI=')
security.tokens.append(token)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
```

My problem is this one: when including UsernameToken, i receive this kind of header:

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>b77a5c561934e089</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>kmfHkNZyn1U/pGAiY3+h0BoHdKI=</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

But what i need is the response to this requirement on web service:

```
<sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:WssUsernameToken10 />
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:UsernameToken>
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
```

How can i do this with suds? Searched whole internet, but didnt find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a SOAP generic solution. Your web service seems to require a custom response.

I presume your authentication does not work?

Try to `marshall` your response into your requester `class`. This [plugin](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.plugin.MessagePlugin-class.html#marshalled) allows you to modify your `soap` envelope. 
You can add your own attributes.

```
class MyRequesterClass(object):

    class _myServiceMarshalled(MessagePlugin):

        def marshalled(self, context):
            commons.set_service_common_header(context, "yourService")

            body = context.envelope.getChild('Body')
            service = body.getChild("childWhereYouWantAddYourCustomXML")

            service.attributes.append(Attribute("sp:IncludeToken", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"))

            etc, etc
```

Comment: What is `commons` in this example?